# How to add gradient on overlapping paths? Is there a way to combine overlapping paths to a single one?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, gradient, path-effects

I have been searching through the internet for a couple of days now and cannot find the answer.

I am trying to add a gradient stroke on a path, a gradient that would make it seem that the path is glowing.

[image]

That is easy.

Until you have multiple overlapping paths that are not suppose to be connected ( Paths > Join not helping here). Instead of having a "flat" path which emanates flaming light evenly, it becomes this silly effect that the light drops a shadow on the path below.
[image]

So clearly I have tried Paths > Join, which results in added additional lines between separate paths and the effect ended up looking worse.
[image]

I have tried "Compound Path" as well to a similar result. 
At this point, it seems to me that there is no way to make overlapping crossed paths to look like a symbol and have an effect added evenly. I searched the web on this, not finding anyone asking this question or any guide on the issue. I might as well be overlooking some simple checkbox, but nothing is coming to my mind after experimenting for couple of days now with effects, appearances, and strokes.

If anyone has a workaround or has solved it for their own projects, I would very much appreciate the help. Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Err.. why are they supposed to be joined? You can not make a shape like this with joined paths.

Comment: My idea was that if the paths are joined, the effect of glow maybe would be even and not have the overlapping shadowy effect. Causing the symbol to emanate evenly the glow.

Comment: No that wont obviously work. St5roke with a black and white colro ramp, put mode to lighten and apply gradient mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must make a Compound Path for the selected paths and use the Appearance panel to assign additional strokes and fills. Do not use black for the color of an end point on the gradient.

[image]

Additional help image. Appearance panel settings.

[image]

Comment: Looks great, will definitely try it out today! Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] this answer if you want to add more images, instead of posting a new answer.

Comment: Doesn't *have* to be a compound shape/path.. a group with a stroke applied to it would also work.